# Site Title in my Search URL

Tags: search, urls

First off, I am still learning Wordpress by building my own theme. Go easy on me.

My search URL displays my sites title. Example: `/My%20Site?s=horror`

Is there an issue with my searchform.php that is causing this? If its the `bloginfo();` then what can I use as a replacement?

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('search'); ?>" id="searchform" method="get">
  <input name="s" class="nav-search" type="text" placeholder="Search Videos">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>` as the action. 'search' by the way is not a valid `bloginfo` parameter.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help :) ill look up `home_url();` on the codex for more info.